# Making an aim trajectory using a line renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[The reference of a trajectory line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTOFX.jpg)

Hey, i'm new to unity and trying to create a trajectory line with the help of a line renderer but it doesn't seem to be working. I have attached my movement script below. It would be very helpful if someone helps me out.

```
public void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //press
    {
        startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        startPoint.z = 15;
        direction = endPoint - startPoint;
        transform.right = direction;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDots; i++)
        {
            trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.01f);
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) //release
    {
        endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        endPoint.z = 15;

        force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - endPoint.x, minPower.x, maxPower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - endPoint.y, minPower.y, maxPower.y));
        rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ignore the for loop that was something I was trying to do instead of the line renderer but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use 'trajectoryDots[i].transform.position' to set the position. There is an explicit .SetPosition() function for lineRenderers.

Try looking into this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html

That might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Line render don't have transforms for all it's position.

So u can't set the transform's position.  Instead use lineRenderer.SetPosition function to set the position of the point in the line along with the index.

Comment: One should always accept and upvote the answer if it helps.